# RDPing Windows 10 freezes every few seconds, 15 minutes after reboot

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access

I RDP into a windows 10 machine at work. After rebooting the remote machine it works, fine for about 15 minutes and then the delays starts to happen every few seconds.

I tried:

- Disabling UDP from client remote connection in group policy.
- Power cycling modem. I tried different connection. Same issue. Both connections have no issues with speed or latency. This issue just appeared after a reboot.
- Disabling heavy services and hyper-v (I use Docker).
- Disabling visual stuff and restricting to one screen. Disabling all local resources: clipboard, smart cards, drives, audio, etc.
- Confirmed that it works fine when I am at the physical machine. So it's definitely network related issue.
- Tried three different RDP clients located on different machine.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by setting display sleep to never.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how and where you set this?  … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.